# Ubuntu: Export and install modules manually

Tags: ubuntu, kernel-modules

I want to export a module (WiLAN controller) that is already installed on my machine and create a file that could install the same module on a fresh new Ubuntu server installation on the same machine.

Installing over internet is not an option since I do not have access to LAN cable and even Ubuntu desktop distributions don't come prepackaged with this proprietary WiLAN module. Let alone Ubuntu Server distribution.

I want to export this installable package to a USB drive and install it that way.

Here is the module name as appears on Ubuntu GUI.
[image: Text]

**Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 LTS**

Thank you!

Comment: Using `apt-offline` should work. What is the Linux distro which has connection to internet? Is it Ubuntu?

Comment: Just edited the question to reflect this: Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 LTS @EdgarMagallon.

Comment: This is great @EdgarMagallon. How do I figure out which driver is the one in the picture? I can ```apt list | grep [keyword]``` but not sure what to use.

Comment: The package name seems to be `bcmwl-kernel-source`. But you'll have to download that package by using `apt-offline`. Using `apt-offline` is the best way to achieve what you want. since this will download the package and all its dependencies.

Comment: However, check if you have installed `apt-offline` in your Ubuntu with no internet connection . If you also don't have `apt-offline` in that machine then you will have to install it by using the deb package (or building it if you are unable to install it)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly address the raised question. I played around with the idea of using `apt-offline` to first download the installed package, and install it on the machine without network. The problem is that `apt-offline` itself doesn't come default with any of the distributions so you end up needing to download apt-offline and compile it in the machine without internet which raises the quesiton; if you want to bother with compiling why not compile the original module in the first place.

What I ended up doing was to use my phone's USB tethering when installing Ubuntu Server. It's pretty amazing how both iPhone and most android tethering connection (through USB) is readily recognized by Ubuntu even in the installation procedure.

I suggest you use your phone's USB tethering while you're installing Ubuntu server, since if you leave it for later many of the required dependencies won't be downloaded and you might not be able to use tethered connection after installation. (Keep in mind that as of Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 LTS, for basic installation you need an additional ~300MB of download).

After I had my server up and running, I used my tether connection to download Macbook Air wifi driver using `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`. Since Ubuntu Server uses netplan for net management you need to also install a package that supports wifi wpa module `sudo apt install wpasupplicant`. After that headed over to config `/etc/netplan/[file_name].yaml` file adding network SSID and Password, then `sudo netplan apply` got me up and running on my wifi.